# Mocking WebOperationContext

Tags: moq, wcf-rest, weboperationcontext

I'm using the [WCFMock](http://wcfmock.codeplex.com/) to mock the WebOperationContext in my web service. The only usage is to add a custom HTTP header to the WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers collection. I'm unable to verify this using Moq. What I've already tried:

- Verify if the Add method is getting invoked. This fails because Add is not virtual
- Try to access the header directly from MockedWebOperationContext.Current. This is always zero in number

How can I verify in my unit test case that a custom header has been added?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Here's the solution for posterity.

When we create the "moq mock" for the IWebOperationContext, the example suggests that we set the property `DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock`. This will mock all dependincies including the HttpHeaders collection. I skipped this and mocked the `OutgoingWebResponseContext` to return a `WebHeaderCollection`. For my test case I simply assert on this collection.

Comment: I'm looking at something pretty close to this problem you had, any chance you can post your code?  I'm missing some conceptual point here and it would greatly help me.

Comment: so looks like this project still works, even though it hasn't had a new version since 2009?